# default php mysqli connection in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I have problem with auto connect to database in php.
I need to configure it using php.ini file or something else.
If i can do this, which the query can i use?

I try to configure it, but it right or wrong?:

```
mysqli.default_socket=
mysqli.default_host="localhost"
mysqli.default_user="root"
mysqli.default_pw=""
mysqli.reconnect=On
```

Additional information:

First, i need to hide mysql host, user and password in php code, but not use the include or something.
Secondly, I want to be able to conveniently use.

Comment: You mean to say that auto reconnect ?

Comment: Use mysqli queries without "$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");" (hide database user and password in ihp code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try to configure it, but it right or wrong?

Yes, it's right. You can omit quotes though.

> If i can do this, which the query can i use?

Not sure what you ask, but in case you are asking for the connection code, it would be as simple as that:

```
$db = mysqli_connect();
$db->select_db('test');
```

Note that you cannot define the database name this way and thus have to set it explicitly using the corresponding function.

Comment: Can i use $db = new mysqli(); to use standard mysqli queries?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have to call this line only once, and then use this `$db` variable to run queries (standard or non standard, whatever it means)  all the way around